# ValidationMessageFor not showing up in boostrap modal

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap-3

Inside my bootstrap modal is a form. When I click the submit button , the validation message error is not showing up. (I intend to enter/input invalid data). I reload the boostrap modal if there is detected error , and I do this in the controller in order to keep the modal open. Is there a different approach here? I wonder why the error message doesn't show up.

Model:

```
    [Display(Name="Email:")]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address!")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
```

View:

```
    @Html.LabelFor(e => e.Email, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
    @Html.EditorFor(e => e.Email, new {htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "required" } })

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
//for submit button
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
           //Proceed to Saving 
            }
           //Keep modal open to show validation message
            TempData["HasError"] = "YES";
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
 //Index action
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {   
        //send this in frontend to know if bootstrap modal will reload
        ViewBag.Status = TempData["HasError"];

            return View();                       
    }
```

Frontend / js

```
        <script>
        $(function (){
        var x = '@status';
        //show the modal of registration form since there is a validation     message error
       if (x == "YES") {
       var tab = 'SignupFrm';
       $('#' + tab).addClass("tab-pane fade in active");
       $('.nav-tabs a[href="#' + tab + '"]').tab('show');
       $('#mLogin').modal('show');

        }
       })
       </script>
```

Comment: Are you loading the form in the modal dynamically?

Comment: no, I have a button that shows the modal and the form is already there.

Comment: Then perhaps show your code :)

Comment: please see the code :-)

Comment: You have not really shown anything relevant to your question. Whay do you have `required = "required"` (HTML5 validation) and `@ValidationMessageFor()`? - if you want it to be required, then your property should have the `[Required]` attribute. If you have a `<input type="submit" .../>` and have included the relevant scripts, then you form will not submit

Comment: please see the model, I;m expecting to see that error message if the input is invalid.

Comment: Have you included the relevant scripts - `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` (and no disabled client side validation)?

Comment: no, but I have jquery 2.1.4 min.js, I started this project file from scratch

Comment: That will not give you any client side validation, and you need to add the 2 scripts I mentioned above. But in any case, your redirecting back to the `Index()` method in the POST method is `ModelState` is invalid so all the values of your form and all the `ModelState` errors are lost. I need a break, but will add an answer explaining the issues and how to solve it with and without client side validation in an hour or so.

Comment: alright , will try first to add those two js. thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comments, you have not included the scripts for client side validation, so first step is to include them (after your `jquery 2.1.4 min.js` script)

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

or better (assuming your have the default bundles in your `BundleConfig.cs` file)

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Assuming you have not turned off client side validation, then this will now display the validation error message(s) when you click the form's submit button and cancel the submit (your controller POST method will not be hit).

However, you still need to handle it in the server in case a malicious user by-passes it. Currently, if your model is not valid, you do a redirect to the GET method, which means that `ModelState` is lost. Instead you need to return the view, and to ensure the modal is reopened, you can add a `ViewBag` property or just check for `ModelState` errors in the view). Your POST method should be (note I am assuming the model is `Person.cs`)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Person model) // modify class name to suit
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ViewBag.HasErrors = true;
    return View(model);
  }
  // save and redirect
}
```

Then in your script

```
$(function () {
  if ('@ViewBag.HasErrors') {
    // display the modal
  }
)};
```

An alternative to adding a `ViewBag` property would be to use the following

```
$(function () {
  if ('@ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.Values.SelectMany(v => v.Errors).Any()') {
    // display the modal
  }
)};
```

Side note: You have added `required = "required"` to your textbox suggesting you want the `Email` to be required. Adding this attribute does not give you server side validation and adding the jquery validation scripts means it will be ignored (the `novalidate="novalidate"` attribute is added to your `<form>` element). Remove it and instead add the `RequiredAttribute` to your property so that you get both client and server side validation.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="Please enter an email address")]
[EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Address!")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: The email validation works now, :-) But the error message pops up even if I'm not clicking the submit button. Can I ask why is it not working if I replace the @Html.EditorFor with @Html.TextBoxFor? I'm new to mvc.  Where can I configure the css for error message? Thanks for the help! voted and accepted. I salute :-)

Comment: That's how client side validation works. If you enter an invalid value and tab out of the control, the error message is displayed (so the user can correct). Are you wanting the message to be displayed only when you click the submit button? (you can override the default behavior).

Comment: If you inspect the html your generating when an error is displayed, you will see class names added to both the input and the associated span that displays the error (`class="input-validation-error"` and `class="field-validation-error"`) so you can style them using css.

Comment: Based on the attributes you have shown for the `Email` property, there will be no difference between using `EditorFor()` and `TextBoxFor()` - they will produce exactly the same html - so I assume you have omitted something from your code.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check if the generated input's **"id"** and (I think) **"name"** attributes match the validation's `<span>` **"data-valmsg-for"** attribute.
I had a case where I needed custom values for these had the same issue for validation message not showing on client and that was my solution:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("newMarkValue", new { @class = "text-danger" })
@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => item.NewMark, null, "newMarkValue", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Renders the validation `<span>` as:

```
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="newMarkValue" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

And the input, according to the property's Range attribute **[Range(2,6, ErrorMessage="Range 2 - 6."]** as:

```
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field NewMark must be a number." data-val-range="Range 2 - 6." data-val-range-max="6" data-val-range-min="2" data-val-required="The NewMark field is required." id="newMarkValue" name="newMarkValue" type="number" value="0">
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried everything from above but nothing seems to work for me.
I tried [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1134796/Display-model-error-on-same-popup-dialog-in-MVC) , just wrote the script part in my partial view and everything worked.

Comment: would have appreciated if had got a reason with a down vote, just for my knowledge as I had the same scenario.